# Lose one's marbles

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is the idiom **lose one's marbles** commonly used in American casual speech? Also, is it used only in the true sense of the word for peoples who started developing Alzheimer's or  can it be used as a figure of speech as well when we want to say that someone lost the ability to make a proper judgment?

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[It's used in Idaho, and seems sufficiently well-known to be used in news headlines.](https://www.eastidahonews.com/2020/06/charles-vallow-says-lori-vallow-daybell-has-lost-her-marbles-in-newly-released-911-calls/)

I  hear it all the time and never to describe the early onset of Alzheimer's.

Comment: Is it OK to say **she started losing her marbles after she had a stroke?** referring to a real deterioration of mental power.

Comment: It's grammatically correct but could be considered, at best, insensitive, and, at worst, offensive, due to the fact that is is a mental illness.  You can say that a politician is losing his marbles and no one would care.

Comment: I understand we got to be careful when talking about the mental condition of someone especially the seniors but my question is can we use it to describe a real mental illness? and what informal word we could use for people who are getting old and start losing their mental abilities?

Comment: It's fine for a group of schoolboys to walk past old-man Wilson's house and say 'the guy who lives there is losing his marbles'. However, a medical professional would not use that phrase.

Comment: Sure, a medical professional would use a formal word when talking to the patient family. What I was looking for is informal word that's used in day-to-day casual speech.

Answer (score 1):

It can be used also in a general sense:

> ***[lose (all) one's marbles](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lose+(one%27s)+marbles)*** and *lose one's mind*.

> Fig. to go crazy; to go out of one's mind.

> - *What a silly thing to say! Have you lost your marbles? Look at Sally
>   jumping up and down and screaming. Is she losing all her marbles? I
>   can't seem to remember anything. I think I'm losing my mind.*

(Collins)